# substitution operator :s in VIM in unix

Tags: unix, vim, substitution

In unix,  while using VIM and the substitue command  I am unable to replace the value to a string containing special character `/`

```
 :%s/var1/"ab1/ab2/ab3"/g
```

I need to replace the entire file containing `var1` with `ab1/ab2/ab3`

Output in vim I see: `Trailing characters`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+substitute+slash

Answer (score 0):

Escape both `/` like so `\/`.....